# Why is isDirectory true for File("c:")?

Tags: java

When I create a File object like

```
File f = new File("c:")
```

and then call the method `isDirectory()`, it returns `true`. **Why is that?**

The program is suppose to show all files in that directory and works fine except when Im using the "c:". It is not accessing "c:\", not the home path, but the directory the program is executing from. I really don't understand.

Comment: How do you come to your conclusion? What does f.getAbsolutePath() print? To me it is perfectly logical that isDirectory() returns true on the root.

Comment: And if the goal it to access c:\ why do you use c: instead of c:\?

Comment: @Gimby Yes. But it doesn't show the files in the root-directory. It shows the files in the directory where the program is executing from. This is an interesting problem....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Windows, a current working directory is kept for each drive (A:, B:, C: etc).

When you use a drive without specifying a directory, you are referring to the current working directory of that drive.

```
C:   refers to the current working directory of drive C:
C:\  refers to the root directory of drive C:
```

In your case, the current working directory for C: is the directory where the program file resides.

Answer (score 0):

This is an interesting question. I'll try to expand on your question (questions should always come with an SSCCE whenever possible)...

Take this code for example:

```
public class Main{

 public static void main(String[] args){
        File f = new File("C:\\");
        System.out.println("C:\\ is directory: " + f.isDirectory());
        System.out.println("C:\\ exists: " + f.exists());
        System.out.println("C:\\ absolute path: " + f.getAbsolutePath());
        System.out.println();

        f = new File("C:");
        System.out.println("C: is directory: " + f.isDirectory());
        System.out.println("C: exists: " + f.exists());
        System.out.println("C: absolute path: " + f.getAbsolutePath());
        System.out.println();

        f = new File("X:");
        System.out.println("X: is directory: " + f.isDirectory());
        System.out.println("X: exists: " + f.exists());
        System.out.println("X: absolute path: " + f.getAbsolutePath());
        System.out.println();
    }
```

}

(Note that I do have a C: drive, I do not have an X: drive)
This results in this output:

C:\ is directory: true
C:\ exists: true
C:\ absolute path: C:\

C: is directory: true
C: exists: true
C: absolute path: C:\Users\kworkman\Desktop\Tests

X: is directory: false
X: exists: false
X: absolute path: X:

So it seems to handle the C:\ correctly, but C: by itself results in strange output for a directory that doesn't actually exist. This is made stranger because it seems to handle the X: case correctly.

Answer (score -1):

Try `C:\` instead.

```
File f = new File("C:\\");
System.out.println(f.getAbsolutePath());
System.out.println(f.isDirectory());
System.out.println(f.isFile());
```

Output:

```
C:\
true
false
```